# Change container "outside" of the selector

Tags: html, css

I have a complex websites which consists of containers. My goal is to check a class on a div container if the class is "active" and if so, I need to color another container which is "far" outside of that container. So the Code looks like this:

```css
.tooltip:has(tooltip > div.active)~main-view>div.colorme {
  background: orange
}
```

```html
<div class="tooltip">
  <tooltip>
    <div class="active">
      My tooltip is active
    </div>
  </tooltip>
</div>
<div class="othercontainer">
</div>
<main-view>
  <div class="colorme">
    Test
  </div>
</main-view>
```

And I want to color the div with class `colorme` as soon as the `<tooltip>` tag has a container with class `active`. I am not sure if this is in general possible, but I thought I could build something like this.

Comment: I've converted your code to a live demo and added a visible effect in the ruleset. It works fine when I test it in a browser that supports `:has`. Obviously it doesn't if I test it in [one that doesn't](https://caniuse.com/?search=has).

Comment: not possible. but if you can use javascript, it makes it possible.

Comment: You are great, thank you! In general this is not my website and I am only able to use the HTML what I pasted. But I was not aware to use the parent container in order. So this works like a chmarn and I know check in <body> if there is a class "active" in order to change "colorme". Thanks guys for the help and the quick response! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a parent container and then use `:has()` pseudo selector like below:

```css
.common-parent:has(tooltip .active) main-view .colorme{
    color: orangered;
}
```

```html
<div class="common-parent">
    <div class="tooltip">
        <tooltip>
            <div class="active">
                My tooltip is active
            </div>
        </tooltip>
    </div>

    <div class="othercontainer">
    </div>

    <main-view>
        <div class="colorme">
            Test
        </div>
    </main-view>
</div>
```

Comment: Keep in mind that `:has` is **not supported by Firefox** - https://caniuse.com/css-has

Comment: Yes, I am aware about that :)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this won't really be possible since the `:has` CSS selector is not really well supported right now. See the support table here: https://caniuse.com/css-has - no Firefox support, and that's a pretty big piece of the browser market share.

Other than that, your logic seems sound.  But to get this working in a better way might be to add/remove a class to a parent element.  This will be easier to understand, and require less complex CSS

```html
<div id="wrapper" class="has-active-tooltip">
  <div class="tooltip">
    <tooltip>
      <div class="active">
      My tooltip is active 
      </div>  
     </tooltip>
  </div>
  <div class="othercontainer"></div>
  <main-view>
   <div class="colorme">
    Test
   </div>
  </main-view>
</div>
```

```css
#wrapper.has-active-tooltip main-view > .colorme {
  /*stuff here*/
}
```